# how to escape multiple hierarchy quotes in string (HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I am working on application with java as backend and Angularjs 1.0 for Front end. I am using veasy Angularjs plugin to show datatable. Now I have managed and tweaked veasy plugin to customize a lot for my app.

Now I am stuck on silly thing, I know how to escape an quote by prefixing "\". But problem here is as I am using multiple hierarchy of quotes both single and double and I am not able to add another quote without breaking the HTML.

**Flow of the code:**

That is a Json that will pass to veasy table. one of the key in that JSON will have HTMl as its value, I have already compiled it in Angularjs, & Its working.

code has a div with bootstrap popover on focus and it also has an attribute that contains html for that popover, now html content has many li for which I need to add ng-click (to each li) with function that passes string value

what I need is to pass a value (string) with that function (`changevehicle()`) but I am not able to add quotes in it, as soon I add a quote there, HTML is broken.

I have tried doing this and a lot: `changevehicle(\'string\')`, I have tried with single quotes double quotes with and without esaping.

I guess my question is not clear. the below code is working, but when I add string value to that function as an argument (`changevehicle()`), HTML is broken.

```
{[vehicle : "<div class='curp use-ellipsis' data-trigger='focus'  tabindex='0'  role='button'  jobplanningpopover popover-html4='<ul class=\"list-unstyled\"><li class=\"emph curp\" ng-click=\" changevehicle() \">xxxxxY 2P<\/li><li class=\"curp\">CHIILL 6P<\/li><li class=\"curp\">NKL 235<\/li><li class=\"curp\">KHD 654<\/li><li class=\"curp\">YET 874<\/li><\/ul>' popover-placement4='bottom' > {{ xxxxxvehicle }} <\/div>"]}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

sometime you just need fresh eyes for a problem , today I solved it in just few minutes

below code worked for me

```
{[vehicle : "<div class='curp use-ellipsis' data-trigger='focus'  tabindex='0'  role='button'  jobplanningpopover popover-html4='<ul class=\"list-unstyled\"><li class=\"emph curp\" ng-click=\" changevehicle("+"&#39;_string_&#39;"+") \">xxxxxY 2P<\/li><li class=\"curp\">CHIILL 6P<\/li><li class=\"curp\">NKL 235<\/li><li class=\"curp\">KHD 654<\/li><li class=\"curp\">YET 874<\/li><\/ul>' popover-placement4='bottom' > {{ xxxxxvehicle }} <\/div>"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `&quot;` in the place of escaped quotes should do the trick. HTML recognizes this as an escaped quotation mark.

```
"<div class='curp use-ellipsis' data-trigger='focus'  tabindex='0'  role='button'  jobplanningpopover popover-html4='<ul class=&quot;list-unstyled&quot;"><li class=&quot;emph curp&quot; ng-click=&quot; changevehicle() &quot;>xxxxxY 2P<\/li><li class=&quot;curp$quot;>CHIILL 6P<\/li><li class=&quot;curp&quot;>NKL 235<\/li><li class=&quot;curp&quot;>KHD 654<\/li><li class=&quot;curp&quot;>YET 874<\/li><\/ul>' popover-placement4='bottom' > {{ xxxxxvehicle }} <\/div>"]
```

Comment: code I wrote in my question is working but when I try to add argument to my function then HTML is broken.

please find "changevehicle()" function call on ng-click

Comment: one thing did change after using or code (after removing extra "),

now html is not broken but ng-click is no more working,

   `ng-click=&quot; changevehicle(&quot; sfdsf &quot; ) &quot;`

Comment: It could be that javascript isn't recognizing `&quot;` as an escaped quote but HTML is. What about leaving the html parts of the code as `&quot;` and escaping the quotes inside of the function: `ng-click=&quot; changevehicle("\ sfdsf \" ) &quot;`

Comment: sorry that code should read `ng-click=&quot; changevehicle(\" sfdsf \" ) &quot;`

Comment: still ng-click is not working, anyway I would like to share, I am compiling the code with $compile service. 

First in Popover content (inner popover-html4) and second on showing html (outer div) on td

Comment: also angularjs is throwing parse error, maybe because it does not recognizes that quotes in function argument as string quotes. 

hence `ng-click` is not working